# ActiveMQ Artemis blocks on createQueueConnection

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

I'm implementing custom log4j appender for sending logs to jms queue, at initialization of connection with this code:

```java
QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) jndi.lookup("QueueConnectionFactory");
QueueConnection queueConnection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
Queue queue = (Queue) jndi.lookup("dynamicQueues/LogQueue");
QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false,
            Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
QueueSender queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queue);
queueConnection.start();
```

queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection() call blocks execution and never ends.

Last things in server logs:

```java
18:54:09.038 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] WARN (NettyConnection.java:506) AMQ212041: Timed out waiting for netty channel to close
18:54:09.038 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] WARN (NettyConnection.java:506) AMQ212041: Timed out waiting for netty channel to close
```

In Artemis logs:

```java
ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred.
```

Thread-dumps at time of this block and later doesn't distinguish and contains:

```java
"RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1" #18 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000002102c800 nid=0x11234 in Object.wait() [0x0000000021eb8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000007af824518> (a io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroupFuture)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.awaitUninterruptibly(DefaultPromise.java:243)
        - locked <0x00000007af824518> (a io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroupFuture)
        at io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroupFuture.awaitUninterruptibly(DefaultChannelGroupFuture.java:183)
        at io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroupFuture.awaitUninterruptibly(DefaultChannelGroupFuture.java:40)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.close(NettyConnector.java:720)
        - locked <0x00000007af7fdcd0> (a org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.checkCloseConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:882)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.closeCleanSessions(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:452)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.interruptConnectAndCloseAllSessions(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:427)
        - locked <0x00000007af823d70> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.cleanup(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:471)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:811)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:844)
        - locked <0x00000007af7cdf58> (a org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQQueueConnectionFactory)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:333)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:329)
        ... common stacktrace 
        at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:117)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000006c3830398> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

According to stacktrace it blocks in org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl at factory.cleanup() when connectionTimedOutOnReceiveTopology exception must be thrown.

```java
if (this.topology != null && !factory.waitForTopology(this.callTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            factory.cleanup();
            throw ActiveMQClientMessageBundle.BUNDLE.connectionTimedOutOnReceiveTopology(this.discoveryGroup);
        } else {
            this.addFactory(factory);
            return factory;
        }
```

Facing this issue using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.7.0 single node and also 2 active/passive nodes cluster.

Are there any possible client configuration or connection code mistakes which can provoke such an error? Or any way to find cause?

Update:

`InitialContext` created manually with these code. Tried adding `?type=QUEUE_CF` to `java.naming.provider.url`, problem remained.

```java
Properties env = new Properties();
env.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
env.put("java.naming.provider.url", "(tcp://artemis-1:61616,tcp://artemis-2:61626,tcp://artemis-2:61616,tcp://artemis-1:61626)?reconnectAttempts=-1");
Context jndi = new InitialContext(env);
```

Corresponding acceptor config in broker.xml is default. Tried adding `;handshake-timeout=0`, it only removed Artemis log.

```
<acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>
```

Comment: How is your JNDI `InitialContext` created and set up? Also, how is the corresponding acceptor in your broker.xml configured?

Comment: Hello, Justin. I'm updated question with new information. Can you please share any ideas on possible solution? Also we have some Axis2 services with JMS transport, which successfully working with the same broker, but i didn't found any significant differences in jms connection code and jndi config for them.

Comment: The code and configuration look OK to me. It looks like something very strange is happening with the network connection. Can you try using Artemis 2.9 and running the app and the broker on the same machine to eliminate any environmental network issues?